# Task 'install' is ambiguous in root project 'TestApp'. Candidates are: 'installDebug', 'installDebugAndroidTest'

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, jcenter

I am working on one library project in android. I want to upload my library to the JCenter. I have created bintray account etc & followed all steps which are mentioned here http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

I did below changes in my application module & library module.

## Application Module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':testlib')
}
```

## Library Module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'test-sdk'

    publishedGroupId = 'in.test.sdk'
    libraryName = 'testlib'
    artifact = 'test-sdk'

    libraryDescription = 'A wrapper for Facebook Native Like Button (LikeView) on Android'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/xyz/testsdk'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/xyz/testsdk.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.0.0'

    developerId = 'xyz'
    developerName = 'xyz'
    developerEmail = 'xyz@xyz.xyz'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

version = "1.0.0"
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           // proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.annotation.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')
}
```

## Project root build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }


}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

When I am doing this `gradlew install` then I am getting this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:          
Task 'install' is ambiguous in root project 'TestApp'. Candidates are: 'installDebug', 'installDebugAndroidTest'.

* Try:                      
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED                

Total time: 11.685 secs
```

I spent three days on same but could not get proper solution of it. Please suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: ./gradlew installDebug

Comment: Hi, Thank a lot, its working but after that i had execute another command that is :-   gradlew bintrayUpload                                   **Again got ERROR : **    'FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
                            
* What went wrong:          
Task 'bintrayUpload' not found in root project 'TestApp'.
                                                        
BUILD FAILED'

Comment: So edit your question about bintrayUpload problems, or close this and open another question.

Comment: Hi Pengrad, i have post the new question as suggested by you, i need your help , Kindly guide me further. New Question [Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305239/task-bintrayupload-not-found-in-root-project-while-executing-command-gradlew-b)

Comment: Hi,

I'm facing the ambiguous root project problem. Can you please guide me what am I missing?

Comment: I had the same problem. Then I realized I was typing this command in the wrong project. BTW, [here's a working bintrayUploadable android library project](https://github.com/LouisCAD/Splitties)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you forgot to add these lines to the end of your Library Module build.gradle:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

Comment: Hi, do you know where exactly these two lines are supposed to be added? Where ever I add it gives error every time.

Comment: @Ari - You need to add it at the end of your library/build.gradle

Comment: what does this 2 lines do ??

Answer (score 2):

You are telling `gradle` to do the '`install`' task but it is telling you that there is no '`install`' task and gives suggestions of close task matches like '`installDebug`'.
Basically your plugins do not include an install task. If you want to see all the tasks that are available to you run the command below

```
gradlew tasks --all
```