# Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins

Tags: maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jcenter

I am working on one library project in android. I want to upload my library to the JCenter. I have created bintray account etc & followed all steps which are mentioned [here](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en).

I did below changes in my application module & library module.

## Application Module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':testlib')
}
```

## Library Module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'test-sdk'

    publishedGroupId = 'in.test.sdk'
    libraryName = 'testlib'
    artifact = 'test-sdk'

    libraryDescription = 'A wrapper for Facebook Native Like Button (LikeView) on Android'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/xyz/testsdk'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/xyz/testsdk.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.0.0'

    developerId = 'xyz'
    developerName = 'xyz'
    developerEmail = 'xyz@xyz.xyz'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

version = "1.0.0"
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           // proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.annotation.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')
}
```

## Latest Project root build.gradle

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
     dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

    }

    plugins {
        id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.2"
    }

    allprojects {

        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }

        apply plugin: 'maven'
        apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
        apply plugin: 'java'
    }
    publishing {
        publications {
            MyPublication(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
                groupId 'in.freeb.sdk'
                artifactId 'freeb-sdk'
                version '1.0'
            }
        }
    }

    bintray {
        user = 'ajay-spice'
        key = '31317855920db8f7bc27f97730a8e9f99b6f707e'
        publications = ['MyPublication']
        pkg {
            repo = 'maven'
            name = 'freeb-sdk'
            userOrg = 'ajay-spice'
            licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
            vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/ajay-spice/freebsdk.git'
            labels = ['gear', 'gore', 'gorilla']
            publicDownloadNumbers = true
            attributes= ['a': ['ay1', 'ay2'], 'b': ['bee'], c: 'cee'] //Optional package-level attributes
            version {
                name = '1.0-Final'
                desc = 'FreeB 1.0 final'
                vcsTag = '1.0.0'
                attributes = ['freeb-sdk': 'in.freeb.sdk']
            }
        }
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.4'
    }
```

When I am building then I am getting this error 
I spent two days on same but could not get proper solution of it. Please suggest how to resolve it.

## Error

```
Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.
Gradle 'FreeBApp' project refresh failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Add in root build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
```

And look at this nice Getting Started https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin

Comment: Hi Pengrad, i am following the tutorial as mentioned by you in above comment. Again i am stuck at one point :                                                  GOT ERROR :- Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: Hi pengrad, i have posted the latest Build.gradle. Kindly check !!

Comment: 'com.android.application' not found - This error has been resolved if i put  dependencies  tag                                                               =========                                                                                                        dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'   }                       But Again Got Error :- Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.

Comment: Hey Pengrad, i have a posted new question , need your help, Kindly Check plz on below Link : [Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377000/execution-failed-for-task-bintrayupload-could-not-create-version-1-1-fina)