# Execution failed for task ':bintrayUpload'. > Could not create version '1.1-Final TestApp': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bintray, jcenter

I am working on one library project in android. I want to upload my library to the JCenter. I have created bintray account etc & followed all steps which are mentioned [here](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en).

I did below changes in my application module & library module.

Application Module build.gradle

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':testlib')
}
```

Library Module build.gradle

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'test-sdk'

    publishedGroupId = 'in.test.sdk'
    libraryName = 'testlib'
    artifact = 'test-sdk'

    libraryDescription = 'A wrapper for Facebook Native Like Button (LikeView) on Android'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/xyz/testsdk'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/xyz/testsdk.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.0.0'

    developerId = 'xyz'
    developerName = 'xyz'
    developerEmail = 'xyz@xyz.xyz'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

version = "1.0.0"
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           // proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.annotation.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')
}
```

Latest Project root build.gradle

```groovy
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.3.1'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.2"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'java'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        MyPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            groupId 'in.freeb.sdk'
            artifactId 'freeb-sdk'
            version '1.0'
        }
    }
}

bintray {
    user = 'ajay-spice'
    key = '31317855920db8f7bc27f97730a8e9f99b6f707e'
    publications = ['MyPublication']
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'freeb-sdk'
        userOrg = 'ajay-spice'
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/ajay-spice/freebsdk.git'
        labels = ['gear', 'gore', 'gorilla']
        publicDownloadNumbers = true
        attributes= ['a': ['ay1', 'ay2'], 'b': ['bee'], c: 'cee'] //Optional package-level attributes
        version {
            name = '1.0-Final'
            desc = 'FreeB 1.0 final'
            vcsTag = '1.0.0'
            attributes = ['freeb-sdk': 'in.freeb.sdk']
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
:bintrayUpload FAILED                                                                                

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bintrayUpload'.
> Could not create version '1.1-Final FreeB': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [message:Unable to create version 1.1-Final FreeB at 'ajay-spice/maven/freeb-sdk']

* Try:         
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED   

Total time: 22.448 secs
```

Log file in Debug mode

```
:app:install                 
:app:bintrayUpload FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bintrayUpload'.
> Could not create version '1.1-Final FreeB': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [message:Unable to create version 1.1-Final FreeB at 'ajay-spice/maven/freeb-sdk']

* Try:         
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:bintrayUpload'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not create version '1.1-Final FreeB': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [message:Unable to create version 1.1-Final FreeB at 'ajay-spice/mav
en/freeb-sdk']
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask$_bintrayUpload_closure6_closure27_closure31.doCall(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:280)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$1.handleResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:503)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1070)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1044)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:515)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:434)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:383)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$request$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask$_bintrayUpload_closure6.doCall(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:272)
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask$_bintrayUpload_closure6.doCall(BintrayUploadTask.groovy)
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask.bintrayUpload(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:383)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 47 more


BUILD FAILED   

Total time: 45.144 secs
```

Comment: can you run with the `--debug` option, we might have more information about the exchange, usually this error happens when sending a snapshot which is not authorized on bintray

Comment: @FredericHenri :- I have added error logs in question for debugging. Please see ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error indicates that you have tried using **'1.0-Final FreeB'** as the version name which is an invalid version name:

```
message:Unable to create version 1.1-Final FreeB at 'ajay-spice/maven/freeb-sdk'
```

A version name must start with a letter or a number and can only contain letters, numbers and the following symbols: .-_:#@$~

The build.gradle sources in your question shows a valid version name - '1.1-Final', however this is different from the [build.gradle](https://github.com/ajay-spice/Freebsdklib/blob/6c6599bc479f1720a279d329380b61f31a7d2e25/app/build.gradle) in your Github project which is using the invalid version name.

[image]

Comment: i tried the same as you suggested - GOT ERROR                              'FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
               
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bintrayUpload'.
> Could not create version '1.1-Final FreeB': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [message:Unable to create version 1.1-Final FreeB at 'ajay-spice/maven/freeb-sdk']
               
* Try:         
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
               
BUILD FAILED   '

Comment: It is still trying to create the version with the invalid name. You need to make sure that the build file you are running includes the correct version name

Comment: @Frederic Henri , i have posted the logcat in above code . Kindly review and please help us to get rid off from this issue.

Comment: I have tried as you suggested, but still not resolved. Got same error as mention below

Comment: i need one more help. now i got new error while generating build                                                                              'Error:Dependency in.test.test:app:1.0 on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: C:\Users\ch-e01073\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\in.test.test\app\1.0\7249f8040cb8933746cb1979a470718fe67d1554\app-1.0.apk'

Comment: I think this a a subject for a new question